# Assign base class pointer to derived class without using dynamic cast

Tags: c++, pointers, assignment-operator

In this given piece of code,i am trying to assign base class pointer to derived class pointer (downcasting) without using dynamic cast.Using help of assignment operator.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
 int i;
 public:
  A& operator =( const A& b)  
     {
        i = b.i;
        return *this ;
     }
};

class B:public A
{
int j;
public:
B& operator =( const B& c)  
     {
        A::operator=(c);
        j=c.j;
        return *this ;
    }
};

int main()
{
A *a;
B *b;
    b=a;
return 0;
}
```

**It shows error: invalid conversion of A* to B*.**

Comment: Upward cast can be done without casting operator, not other way around

Comment: C++ does NOT do implicit downcasting, you need use `dynamic_cast`. The reason is that when you downcast, "a derived class could add new data members, and the class member functions that used these data members wouldn't apply to the base class." (see http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php )

Comment: @vsoftco  that means there is no way to downcast base class without dynamic casting....Am i right??

Comment: Yes, see also the small tutorial here to understand why http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it by `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast`(be careful of UB in this case) ...

> In C++, run-time type checking is implemented through dynamic_cast.
>   Compile-time downcasting is implemented by static_cast, but this
>   operation performs no type check. If it is used improperly, it could
>   produce undefined behavior [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting#Uses).

and your assignment operators will not help.